# FlashDevelop, only "Build Failed"

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flashdevelop

I'm trying to compile the following program. I have downloaded the TweenMax already added correctly to the folder of the Global Classpaths FlashDevelop as I always do, but when I try to compile it gives the following error in the Output:

> "C: \ MyLibraries \ greensock-as3 \
>   com \ greensock \ TweenLite.as: Error:
>   A file found in the source-path must
>   have the Same package structure'', to
>   the definition's package,
>   'com.greensock'. Build halted with
>   errors (FCSH)."

I've searched various forums for solutions, but nothing decided.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you also have to link them from the FLA.
http://jeffnehlsen.com/2011/02/flashdevelop-the-basics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the TweenMax source code in your project, or do you have the SWC in the library path?

Assuming the former, it sounds like you have the source path incorrectly set.  It should point to: `C:\MyLibraries\greensock-as3\` and then the TweeLight.as file will properly have a package com.greensock.TweenLite.

Based on the error, I assume the source path is pointed at C:\ and if so then the TweenLite package should be `MyLibrarires.greesock.as3.com.greenSock.TweenLite`.

Comment: Thank you, confuse me with the names of the folders as there are two of the same name (as3-greensock).

Comment: Why are their two folders with the same name?